# How to add own project to public maven repository?

Tags: maven, repository, addition, artifact

I'd like to add my project to public maven repository so that it can be used by community. It doesn't have to be maven central - just any kind of public and free repository for open source code.

How do I do that (in easiest way)?

Comment: I'd like to add that project is hosted on GoogleCode and as far as I know there is no way to do that automatically (from GoogleCode)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1280470/maven-repository-for-google-code-project

Comment: Thanks for comment but I'm using Mercurial for my version contoling needs so this SVN solution probably won't work

Comment: Ideally you need to deploy to a proper Maven repo. The following link is another option for doing it via google code: http://www.thewebsemantic.com/2009/04/11/your-very-own-google-code-maven-repo/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Probably 3 ways to do this:

1. If you have a web server you can simply drop the jar and pom into a directory, eg: `yourserver.com/mavenRepo/com/yourcompany/v1.0/yourjar.jar` This is the 'quick and dirty' way, but then the public can add yourserver.com/mavenRepo as a repository.
2. Have an out-facing instance of [Nexus](http://nexus.sonatype.org/) or [Artifactory](http://www.jfrog.com/products.php)
3. Make the project more official through one of the common open source projects, described in the 'Approved Repository Hosting' and the 'Other Projects' sections of [this page](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-central-repository-upload.html).

Comment: Thanks for answer. Here's URL to Sonatype guide https://docs.sonatype.org/display/Repository/Sonatype+OSS+Maven+Repository+Usage+Guide

Comment: @Daimon The link given by you makes 404 error, can you update?

Comment: It's probably here now (you'll also need to check referenced pages as well): http://central.sonatype.org/pages/ossrh-guide.html